# ui.bootstrap not loading despite load order and dependency declaration being correct

Tags: angularjs, module, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have ui.bootstrap loaded in my index.html, but it's triggering an error in the console and preventing the rest of my app from loading. All of the urls are returning the proper file. I've tried swapping the load order around several ways. I've tried declaring the dependency in just one or the other of my main modules. I've checked that the module name is actually 'ui.bootstrap' in the source. This one has me a bit stumped. Most answers that I've seen have to do with load order, but that doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Angular version: 1.3.13

Angular ui-bootstrap version: 0.12.0 pulled from bower install angular-bootstrap

index.html head:

```
  <script src="/lib/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script href="/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/services.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/dirPagination.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/app.js"></script>
  <link href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

bookCatalog declaration:

```
var bookCatalog = angular.module('bookCatalog', [
  'ngRoute',
  'catalogControllers',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'
])
```

catalogControllers declaration:

```
var catalogControllers = angular.module('catalogControllers', [
  'ngRoute', 
  'ui.bootstrap'
])
```

console error log:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bookCatalog due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module catalogControllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-build.3042+sha.76e57a7/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:120:12
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:215:17
    at ensure (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:139:38)
    at module (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:213:14)
    at angular.module (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:686:31)
    at angular.module (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1019:38)
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4097:22
    at forEach (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at loadModules (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4081:5)
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4098:40
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap&p1=Er…0at%20https%3A%2F%2Fxx.xxx.xx.xxx%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4098%3A40
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4120:15
    at forEach (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at loadModules (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4081:5)
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4098:40
    at forEach (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at loadModules (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4081:5)
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4098:40
    at forEach (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at loadModules (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4081:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=catalogControllers…les%20(https%3A%2F%2Fxx.xxx.xx.xxx%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4081%3A5)
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4120:15
    at forEach (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at loadModules (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4081:5)
    at https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4098:40
    at forEach (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at loadModules (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4081:5)
    at createInjector (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:4007:11)
    at doBootstrap (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:1445:20)
    at Object.angular.resumeBootstrap (https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:1474:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=BookCatalog&p1=Err…ap%20(https%3A%2F%2Fxx.xxx.xx.xxx%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1474%3A12)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess  <script src="/lib/app.js"></script> should be place on fourth position

Comment: @squiroid Good thought. Just tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: Is error changed or the same ,.?

Comment: Yep, scanned the console. No change. Cleared the cache, checked in another browser. No change. That's what gets me, there's no difference no matter what I do.

Comment: Bootstrap - The 0.12.1 milestone will be for bug fixes for the existing Angular 1.2 supported version. Taken from https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap. Try using newer version of bootstrap?

Comment: @OrGuz Oh gosh, I feel dumb. Thanks. I don't see an experimental release yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I created a controller. Reviewing the syntax, I found I hadn't defined the controller structure properly. Double check that you have the proper structure for your controller.